# qual a maneira mais simples de printar um texto identado em javascript para html?

Tags: javascript, html

tem como imprimir isso de um jeito mais fácil?

```
        public static void swap(int[] list, int i, int j) {
            /* This method simply takes an array
            and swaps its values at index i and j */

            int temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
```

*Esse foi um modo que eu fiz:*

**HTML**

```
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <span id="codigoJava"></span>
                </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var string = 
        '<textarea wrap="off" readonly style="width:100%; height:400px; overflow:scroll; font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt;">'+"\n"+
        "\t"+"public static void swap(int[] list, int i, int j) {"+"\n"+     
        "\t"+"\t"+"int temp = list[i];"+"\n"+
        "\t"+"\t"+"list[i] = list[j];"+"\n"+
        "\t"+"\t"+"list[j] = temp;"+"\n"+
        "\t"+"}"+"\n"+
        '</textarea>'   
        ;
    document.getElementById('codigoJava').innerHTML = string;
```

se eu criar uma textarea diretamente no html e só printar o código, fica bem mais fácil, não preciso fazer o código da indentação. Mas eu acho que o código fica muito "sujo", então resolvi deixar separado em um javascript pra printar no html. existe uma maneira mais simples de fazer a indentação?

Comment: Boa noite,  alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar a tag `<pre>` para colocar código formatado. Para efeitos de boa prático deves ainda juntar `<code>` para o Browser saber qual é o conteúdo que mostra.

#### Exemplo ([**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mckuuwso/)):

```
<code><pre>
public static void swap(int[] list, int i, int j) {
    /* This method simply takes an array
            and swaps its values at index i and j */

    int temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[j];
    list[j] = temp;
}
</pre></code>
```

Se queres mostrar HTML, então tens de converter o `<` para `&lt;`, o `>` para `&gt;` e o `&` para `&amp;`. Podes mesmo converter aspas e outros caracteres. [Usei este site](https://mothereff.in/html-entities) para o exemplo que coloco em baixo:

Exemplo:

```
<pre><code>
&lt;div class=&quot;modal-body&quot;&gt; 
    &lt;span id=&quot;codigoJava&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
```

que vai dar:

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
    <span id="codigoJava"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi a sua pergunta, acredito que você tenha um código salvo em um banco de dados ou arquivo de texto e você quer exibir a sua fonte em um HTML, se for isto, você pode usar o `<pre>`:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <pre id="codigoJava"></pre>
</div>
```

Você também pode usar CSS combinado com a tag `<code>`:

```js
var myCode = "\t" + "public static void swap(int[] list, int i, int j) {" + "\n" +     
            "\t" + "\t" + "int temp = list[i];" + "\n" +
            "\t" + "\t" + "list[i] = list[j];" + "\n" +
            "\t" + "\t" + "list[j] = temp;" + "\n" +
            "\t" + "}" + "\n";

document.getElementById("codigoJava").innerHTML = myCode.replace(/[<]/g, "&lt;").replace(/[>]/g, "&gt;");
```

```css
#codigoJava {
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 500px;                /* Ajuste conforme a necessidade  */
    display: block;
    background-color: #cfcfcf;

    white-space: pre-wrap;                 /* CSS3 browsers  */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* 1999+ Mozilla  */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;                /* Opera 4 thru 6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;              /* Opera 7 and up */
      word-wrap: break-word;               /* IE 5.5+ and up */
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <code id="codigoJava"></code>
</div>
```