# Texto plano na tag pre html

Tags: html

Estava usando a tag `<pre>` e a tag `<code>` para inserir algo que destacasse um pedaço de código. Porém, quando escrevo a parte de código html nas tags `<pre>` e `<code>` elas reconhecem (no caso a div que estou usando).

Sigam o código aqui e no jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqmau36p/1/

No HTML:

```
<pre>
 <div class="alert warning">
   <b>Ooops!</b> Something glitched.
 </div>
</pre>
```

Como aparece na página:

> **Ooops!** Something glitched.

Como quero que apareça:

```
<div class="alert warning">
   <b>Ooops!</b> Something glitched.
</div>
```

Comment: Não, não tem resposta nisso

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com JavaScript

Comment: Marquei como duplicada de uma outra pergunta que tem respostas que te ajudam. Na resposta que indiquei não uso JavaScript. Existe [outra também](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13106/129). E com [essa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59219/129) dá para fazer isto: http://jsfiddle.net/nqmau36p/2/

Comment: Uma maneira simples seria substituir as *tags* "<" e ">" do HTML por **&lt** e **&gt**.

Exemplo sem mostrar o código:

<form id="frmTeste"> 

Exemplo exibindo o código:

**&lt**form id="frmTeste"**&gt**